# Renewal of J-1 visa in a different consulate

Tags: j-visa, usa

I am currently in the US holding a J-1 visa, which was stamped in the US embassy in Madrid on my Spanish passport and expires this summer.

I need to travel this summer to another country, and I was wondering if I can renew my J-1 visa in the US Embassy there, or I have to go to Madrid again and do it there.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your J-1 visa expiring this summer?

Comment: yes, I clarified it now in the question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may be able to renew your J-1 visa at a US consulate in a country other than your home country, as a 'third country national (TCN).'

Not all US consulates accept TCN, so you would need to check in advance with the specific consulate for its TCN policy.  The [website of the American Embassy](http://www.usembassy.gov/) in that country would have visa instructions in the non-immigrant section.

There are risks; should there be delays, you would have to stay in that country until the processing is complete; you could not reenter the US, of course, until the renewal is approved.

As a point of reference, you're able to do this since you are renewing the same type of visa which you received in your home country (i.e., that of your citizenship or residence).

Comment: However, at many embassy sites there are no references to TCN whatsoever.

Comment: @retrot and that's why you have to check with the embassy; in what country will you be this summer, if I may ask?

Comment: Yep, its Serbia. And the issue is that I also have a Serbian passport, so when I call they seem not to understand what I am asking. They ask me if I have a Serbian passport, and then they and keep saying that with my Serbian passport I can of course apply for a J-1 there... it is quite frustrating talking to them.

Comment: @retrot try an email consbelgrade@state.gov ...Only mention your Spanish passport, that it's a J-1 renewal. At the same time, check with Madrid; if you're able to take care of it in several days, at worst, you could alter your return travel plans.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm, I was able to renew my visa in a consulate of a different country my passport was issued, and also my previous visa. No delays or complications.

Comment: You should edit your question to add this information and accept the other answer and not post another answer for an update.

Comment: @DipenShah I disagree. StackExchange explicitly encouraged answering one's own question, and questions that contain their own answers are confusing.  I do agree that the other answer should be accepted if it led to the solution, but this answer should remain as confirmation.

Comment: @phoog confirmation? That's what accepting an answer is for. What values does a confirmation as another answer add? Shouldn't accepting the answer which actually adds value be the right way here? SE does encourage answering your own question ONLY if you have found a solution which does not exist in the current answers which in this case isn't the case. IMHO this answer should be removed as it doesn't add any value, the other answer should be accepted and if OP wishes, they can add a comment on the other answer as a confirmation or update their OP as this ans doesn't add any value to the site.